# Java JDialog not displaying JTable

Tags: java, user-interface, jdialog

I have the following JDialog class:

```
public class VHSInformationPanel extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable vhsTable;
    private String[][] data;
    private String[] columnNames;
    public VHSInformationPanel(String[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
        this.data = data;
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        vhsTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        add(new JScrollPane(vhsTable,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The data for the JTable is correctly transmitted when the class is iniatilezed, however, when I press to show the JDialog it displays an empty JDialog. Why isn't the JTable contained?

The code that initializes the JDialog is:

```
public void showVHSInformationPanel(String[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
  vhsInformationPanel = new VHSInformationPanel(data, columnNames);
  vhsInformationPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Is it initialized wrong?

Comment: Could you indent your code sensibly please?

Comment: Can we assume you have some data that is passed in?  Have you tried debugging this?  Are you looking at the console to determine whether there is an exception of any sort?

Comment: I have debugged this. The information is correctly passed and no exception is thrown.

Comment: OK. Can you reproduce this problem without data coming in?

Comment: In fact, I have tried adding a simple label to the JDialog. It still didn't show up.

Comment: How about to change your layout to i.e. `BorderLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I made few modifications in your code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class VHSInformationPanel extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable vhsTable;

    public VHSInformationPanel(String[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        vhsTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        add(new JScrollPane(vhsTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED),
                BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I changed `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout` and added `JScrollPane` with `JTable` on `CENTER` of `JPanel`. Also I set proper default close operation for `JDialog` which is dispose on close. And finally I called `pack` so your `JDialog` will adjust its size based on preferred size of `JTable`. Optionally, you can set modality type.

Initialization was not a problem at all.
Test code:

```
String[][] data = { { "bla", "bla" } };
String[] cols = { "col1", "col2" };
new VHSInformationPanel(data, cols);
```

Comment: Indeed, I just figured out that the problem was that I did not set the size of the JDialog. The table was inserted, but it wasn't shown due to the small size of the JDialog. Thank you for your help!